# Describing affection to one person only and not anyone else

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the word or phrase for showing affection to one person only and not anyone else?

For example my parents are buying things only for my brother and not me.... What is the word or phrase for those actions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you may be looking for is

> **favour**
>
> My parents **favour** my brother over me.

Comment: I think the noun form – ***favoritism*** – is better to describe this situation. One dictionary defines it as: _the practice of giving unfair preferential treatment to one person or group at the expense of another._

Answer (score 1):

There is also the expression **[playing favorites](https://books.google.com/books?id=fwNatYrz_tEC&pg=PA32&dq=%22playing%20favorites%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp0Lq-tsfbAhWD2VMKHQERBmQQ6AEIazAM#v=onepage&q=%22playing%20favorites%22&f=false)**.

> They are playing favorites.